# Multiple enchantments on a single player

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can you place multiple copies of one curse, enchantment, on a single player? For example, can one person have multiple [Curse of the Bloody Tome](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCurse%20of%20the%20Bloody%20Tome%5d) placed on them? The enchantment is not legendary but I wasn't sure of the ruling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit on the number of Enchantments that can be attached to an object or player.

In the case of [Curse of the Bloody Tome](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCurse%20of%20the%20Bloody%20Tome%5d), the ability of both Enchantments would trigger at the beginning of enchanted player's upkeep, after which both will be added to the stack, after which the enchanted player will be forced to mill two cards, then another two cards.